# What to return updated column using returning in a sqlu statement, slickexception

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I'm using Postgresql with slick, and I am trying to do the following:

```
sqlu"update table1 set column1 = column1 + 1 where id = $id returning column1".first
```

I am getting the below error.  Basically I want to perform the update, and then get the updated value returned back.

Error:

```
[[SlickException: Update statements should not return a ResultSet]]
```

Is there another way to do this?  It seems you are not allowed to return anything with an update statement?  (returning seems to resemble a result set but it is just a single integer value).

Comment: What if you use sql instead of sqlu and wrap the above in an exec statement ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From slick [source](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/src/main/scala/scala/slick/jdbc/GetResult.fm), it looks like if it is an update, slick throws an error in the `apply` method at line 52 while retrieving the value.

From [staticQuery](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/src/main/scala/scala/slick/jdbc/StaticQuery.scala) source, from line 35 which is dealing with update queries, slick passes the `GetResult.GetUpdateValue` to the rconv, which calls the `apply` method which leads to error if update query is returning a value.

As a workaround, you can directly get hold of the ResultSet using prepared statements and process it yourself like:

```
private val updateQuery = "update test set name = 'mohitttttt' where id = ? returning name"
db.withSession { implicit session =>
      session.withPreparedStatement(updateQuery) { ps =>
      ps.setInt(1, 1)
      val rsetIterator = new ResultSetIterator[String](ps.executeQuery(), rset =>   rset.getString(1))
      rsetIterator.toList.head
}
```

ResultSetIterator is a simple class to process the resultSet

```
class ResultSetIterator[T](rset: ResultSet, mapper: ResultSet => T) extends Iterator[T] {
  def hasNext = rset.next
  def next: T = {
    mapper(rset)
  }
}
```

A `mapper` function tells how to process the ResultSet to get desired object. Above, it is used to convert ResultSet to String. It can be used to convert to any complex object.

Comment: could this be a compiled query somehow?

Comment: Probably not. Performance wise, there will be no difference. Compiled queries lead to SQL statements and just avoid conversion from Slick functions to SQL statements. You already have that by writing the query. Not sure, what will be benefit of having compiled query.

Comment: just trying this out, where exactly is the ResultSetIterator? namespacE?

Comment: thanks, that makes sense now. One point though.  Since the response of the update is always going to be a single column INT value, do I really need an iterator?

Comment: Yes, you don't need an Iterator. I just reused the code which I had.